# codeigniter multiple submit button clicks. ( Not prevent multiple submission or clicks )

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a register form and i have already set email column to be unique in DB so there is no duplicate email to be allowed if a user register with a used email address.

My problem is, if a user register with a new email (means no in DB) and he/she clicking too fast or what. The first submit request will successful insert to the DB and return an error message which is "the email is not available or used".

How to i prevent the second or the rest request if a user clicking too fast?

Note, i need prevent in server side not client side like disable button

Comment: The script is running as expected. What's the issue here? Why you can't disable the the button in client side?

Answer (score 0):

When the registration is successful set a session with some key value and time. So when a registration request come to the server just check if there is already a success registration on the same session in short period of time. If so don't go in to the registration process just display the success message as you would have displayed for the first request.

When there is a validation error you don't need to do anything, because there is no harm in validating the form for the second time.

Note: If you have implemented this by disabling the submit button once clicked will be the easiest solution.